# Каким образом программно зарегистрировать в ОС программу для открытия определенного типа файлов по умолчанию? (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, файлы, python-2.x

Каким образом программно зарегистрировать в ОС программу для открытия определенного типа файлов по умолчанию, а также научить программу понимать, что в ней что-то открывают.

Windows версия вопроса: [Каким образом программно зарегистрировать в ОС программу для открытия определенного типа файлов по умолчанию? (Windows)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581619/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%9e%d0%a1-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd?noredirect=1#comment773732_581619)

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [How to set default program?](http://askubuntu.com/q/90214/3712)

Comment: @jfs, мне нужно чтобы можно было сделать скрипт который устанавливает программу автоматически для формата.

Comment: @MihailRis, 1. вы хотите лишь добавить свой обработчик для существующего mime-типа, или вдобавок ещё и описать новый mime-тип? 2. какое отношение к вопросу имеет python?

Comment: Комментарий не является ответом. Поэтому моя ссылка не призвана ответить на ваш вопрос сама по себе. Linux не Windows, поэтому *"устанавливает программу автоматически для формата"* может работать не так как вы ожидаете (нет assoc, ftype на Linux). Прочитав ссылку, вы могли бы упомянуть: "я хочу вызвать `mimeopen -d .avi` в Питоне" или "я хочу знать как программно отредактировать: `~/.config/mimeapps.list`" (посмотрите как xdg-mime реализован или напрямую этот скрипт вызывайте) или наоборот сказать "я хочу запустить `.py` файлы" (тогда ответ другой: добавьте shebang `#!` и `chmod +x` вызовите).

Comment: Также существует `update-alternatives` механизм, который позволяет выбрать какая конкретно программа запускается по указанным именам таким как `editor`, `display`, `rename`, `java`,  `nc`, etc. Не достаточно информации в вопросе, чтобы понять применим ли он в вашем конкретном случае.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

подробный ответ требует, конечно, подробного разбора как [спецификаций xdg](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/) (касающихся mime-информации вообще и desktop-файлов в частности), так и различных реализаций этих стандартов.

---

а краткий ответ, в стиле «сделайте так, и оно, скорее всего, заработает», может звучать так: *добавьте строку, связывающую desktop-файл вашей программы с нужным вам mime-типом, в файл `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` (некоторые de, вроде бы, используют вдобавок и `/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list`)*.

---

пример:

чтобы по умолчанию при «окрытии» файла с mime-типом `image/png` запускалась программа, описанная в desktop-файле `/usr/share/applications/display-im6.desktop`, добавьте в `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` строку:

```
image/png=display-im6.desktop;
```

если файл до этого не существовал, имеет смысл для «красоты и правильности» первой строкой в нём указать секцию:

```
[Default Applications]
```

---

конечно, это поведение может быть переопределено аналогичным по смыслу пользовательским файлом `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`.

---

общесистемная привязка mime-типов к суффиксам файлов находится в файле `/etc/mime.types`.

общесистемный кэш всех привязок зарегистрированных desktop-файлов к mime-типам находится в файле `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`.

Comment: На разных системах могут разные файлы использоваться, посмотрите на xdg-mime, упомянутую выше—кстати если эта утилита работает на выбранной системе, то вызвать её может быть проще чем руками файлы редактировать.

Comment: @jfs, 1. оговорки про краткость и про «скорее всего заработает» — приведены. 2. xdg-mime изменяет лишь файлы пользователя, не вмешиваясь в общесистемные настройки.

Comment: 1- запустить xdg-mime не  менее "кратко" чем ваше предложение найти файл и отредактировать его самостоятельно, но может быть более переносимо. Это предложение улучшить ответ (иначе бы я свой дал) 2- к чему файловые ассоциации общесистемные менять? (Какой use-case?) Если очень хочется, то из под root можно попробовать запустить? (Не рекомендуемая опция)

Comment: @jfs, на оба пункта один ответ — цитата из вопроса:   «зарегистрировать в ОС программу». я и написал об общесистемных настройках, сознательно опустив как пользовательские настройки (хотя и упомянул о них), так и, естественно, программы для их изменения (*xdg-mime* и вообще пакет [xdg-utils](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/) — далеко не единственная реализация).

Comment: Учитывая неточность языка в вопросе, я бы не пытался на *букву* (две буквы: ОС) особо упирать, так как ответ основанный на mime типах уже больше *дух* нежели *букву* вопроса уважает. Если бы вы хотели буквально ответить, и предираться к словам без дела, то следовало бы сказать: Linux это ядро, а не desktop environment и системных вызовов, регистрирующих программы для типов файлов нет. Linux это не Windows. К чему вы упомянули не единственность xdg-mime не ясно (к примеру мой комментарий упоминает mimeopen наверху. Есть и другие). Конечно, ваше право не улучшать ваш ответ.

Comment: @jfs: ещё раз повторюсь: мною вопрос понят как относящийся к обще-системным настройкам, а не пользовательским (и, тем более, не к программе linux, зачем-то вами упомянутой). если вы хотите раскрыть тему пользовательских настроек в своём ответе, я буду только рад.

Comment: А на Windows как?

Comment: @MihailRis, если у вас возник новый вопрос, вы можете задать его с помощью соответствующей кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: Это к этому вопросу и относится.

Comment: До чужих правок там и Windows тоже был.

Comment: @MihailRis: С Windows совершенно отдельная история, лучше задайте отдельный вопрос (и сошлитесь на этот).

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581619/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%9e%d0%a1-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd Вот.