# Каким образом программно зарегистрировать в ОС программу для открытия определенного типа файлов по умолчанию? (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, файлы, python-2.x

Каким образом программно зарегистрировать в ОС программу для открытия определенного типа файлов по умолчанию, а также научить программу понимать, что в ней что-то открывают.
Linux версия вопроса: [Каким образом программно зарегистрировать в ОС программу для открытия определенного типа файлов по умолчанию? (Linux)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581118/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%9e%d0%a1-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd)

Comment: в [этом ответе на enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8196691/5741205) подробно описано как это сделать средствами Windows. Из Python можно запускать соотв. OS комманды ... PS ваш скрипт должен быть запущен с правами администратора

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте с модулем `winreg` изменить реестр:

```py
import winreg

key = winreg.OpenKey(
    winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    r"Software\Classes")

txtx = winreg.CreateKeyEx(key, ".txtx")
winreg.SetValue(txtx, '', winreg.REG_SZ, 'txtfile')
```

Теперь файлы с расширением .txtx будут открываться в блокноте.