# С чем ассоциировать .desktop файл, чтобы он просто запускался?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

Допустим, у меня по умолчанию в качестве текстого редактора используется Geany. Если я в терминале наберу `xdg-open something.desktop`, то файл откроется в Geany, но мне нужно чтобы он запускался!

На скриншоте вы видите, что в контекстном меню предлагают открыть ярлык офисом, т.е. связанным приложением и это очень неудобно! Я не хочу открывать его офисом, я хочу чтоб в этом меню предлагался текстовый редактор, но текстовый редактор уже является приложением по умолчанию и по этому его там нет.

Мне нужно как-то перенести Geany из разряда "Приложение по умолчанию" в разряд "Связанные приложения", а приложением по умолчанию назначить команду запуска. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

[image: открыть с помощью]

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/239883/416190

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо большое, помогло!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ответ будет (в последней части) пересекаться с другим моим ответом: [Каким образом программно зарегистрировать в ОС программу для открытия определенного типа файлов по умолчанию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581397/178576), но уже не в общесистемном, а в пользовательском контексте.

1. для начала надо уметь извлечь из desktop-файла имя программы (оно указывается в строке, начинающейся с `exec=`):

   1. с помощью такого скрипта:

      ```
      #!/bin/bash
      f=$1
      shift
      $(sed -n '/^Exec=/{s/^Exec=//;s/%.//;p}' $f) "$@" &
      ```
   2. или [такого](https://askubuntu.com/a/239883/416190):

      ```
      #!/usr/bin/python
      from gi.repository import Gio
      import sys 
      def main(myname, desktop, *uris):
          launcher = Gio.DesktopAppInfo.new_from_filename(desktop)
          launcher.launch_uris(uris, None)
      if __name__ == "__main__":
          main(*sys.argv)
      ```

   сохраните его под произвольным именем (например, `deskopen`) в каком-нибудь из каталогов, перечисленных в переменной окружения `$PATH` (например, в `/usr/local/bin`) и присвойте биты исполнимости (`$ chmod +x /путь/к/файлу`).

   теперь desktop-файлы можно «запускать» с помощью этого скрипта:

   ```
   $ deskopen /путь/к/файлу.с.суффиксом.desktop
   ```
2. теперь надо создать desktop-файл, служащий «обёрткой» для вызова этого скрипта:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=deskopen
   Exec=deskopen %U
   MimeType=application/x-desktop
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   ```

   для использования только текущим пользователем его надо поместить под именем `deskopen.desktop` в каталог `~/.local/share/applications`.
3. в том же каталоге (`~/.local/share/applications`) эту ассоциацию — между mime-типом `application/x-desktop` и созданной на предыдущем шаге «обёрткой» надо сделать «умолчальной». в один из файлов — `defaults.list` или `mimeapps.list` — добавьте в секцию `[Default Applications]` строку:

   ```
   application/x-desktop=deskopen.desktop
   ```

   если ни одного из этих двух файлов не существовало — создайте любой из них. тогда он будет выглядеть так:

   ```
   [Default Applications]
   application/x-desktop=deskopen.desktop
   ```

всё. теперь команда

```
$ xdg-open /путь/к/файлу.с.суффиксом.desktop
```

будет запускать упомянутую в этом файле программу, а не редактор для редактирования этого файла.

соответственно, и «файловые менеджеры» будут вести себя аналогично при «щелчке» по такому файлу.

Comment: Сделал все указанное выше. Но не открывает при двойном клике по файлу. Открывает только из терминала:
deskopen /путь/к/файлу.с.суффиксом.desktop xdg-open /путь/к/файлу.с.суффиксом.desktop При этом deskopen.desktop открывается при запуске другого ярлыка, но через пол секунды пропадает как будто ничего и не было запущено. Вручную если открываю программу через этот deskopen тоже самое. Работает только из терминала.