# Запуск ярлыка на рабочем столе

Tags: linux

Как запустить ярлык на рабочем столе через терминал?
Система Arch linux xfce.
Конкретно создал ярлык виртуальной машины на рабочем столе.
xdg-open не запускает

Comment: ярлык запускается двойным щелчком мышки

Comment: В этом и вопрос запустить этот ярлык

Answer (score 1):

Способ ручной - открыть файл, он текстовый, найти секцию `Desktop Entry`, в ней ключ Exec. Там будет строка запуска. Распарсить можно как ручками, так и готовыми модулями. Например, для Perl есть такое [File::DesktopEntry](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::DesktopEntry). или для [python](https://github.com/rafpyprog/desktop-entry).

Если нужно просто в терминале запустить, тогда можно так

```
xdg-open file.desktop
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585249/178576

Comment: Неполучаеться запустить

Comment: что значит "не получается запустить"? выключается комп, синий экран, на экран выводиться какое-то сообщение (а ещё скопировать содержимое консоли)

Comment: Не получаеться запустить. Вот я его запускаю ручками(он работает).А когда пишу  xdg-open Получаю : /usr/bin/xdg-open: строка 854: www-browser: команданда не найдена

Comment: сделайте ls -al `www-browser*` и покажите вывод

Comment: zsh: no matches found: www-browser*

Comment: что же Вы тогда запускаете, я думал это www-browser

Comment: Я запускаю virtualbox, это ярлык машины. Я хочу удаленно по zsh запускать ее.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно папка рабочего стола находится по адресу '~/Desktop', но это может быть и "'Рабочий стол"'. Заходите через терминал в эту папку и пишите ./имя ярлыка - должно работать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585249/178576