# как запустить .desktop в ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: ubuntu

Если в ubuntu 18.04 это делалось кликом по на файл то в ubuntu 19.04 открывается desktop текстовом редакторе. Как его запустить?

Comment: видимо, дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585249/178576

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [С чем ассоциировать .desktop файл, чтобы он просто запускался?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585249/%d0%a1-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-desktop-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0):

1. Разрешить выполнение файла как программы.

   chmod +x *.desktop
2. В параметрах файлового менеджера Nautilus, во вкладке "Поведение" для исполняемых текстовых файлов, выбрать опцию "Запустить":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]